# EXTJS Extending Ext.data.JsonStore

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm an ExtJS (I'm using version 5.1) newbie and I'm trying to split a monolithic single file application in different files. I've moved a store outside in a separate file. This is the store in the separate file:

```
Ext.define("MT.store.MicroProfilerStore", {

    extend: "Ext.data.JsonStore",

    singleton : true,
    model  : 'MT.model.MicroProfilerModel',
    storeId: "micro_profiler_store",
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: './backend/profiler.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'answers'
        }
    }
});
```

If I use this file the ajax request is correct and I can see the reply but it looks like the store is ignoring the rootProperty and instead of having the array of answers in the store.getData() I have a single item array with the first value that is the entire response converted to javascript like:

```
[{success: 'true', answers: [{}, {}]}]
```

But If I create the store directly without subclassing using Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore", {...}) it's working!

The hack that I've found after a day of trying that allows me to keep a separate file for the store is this:

```
Ext.define("MT.store.MicroProfilerStore", function(){
    Ext.require(['MT.model.MicroProfilerModel'], function(){
        Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore", {
            singleton : true,
            model  : 'MT.model.MicroProfilerModel',
            storeId: "micro_profiler_store",
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: './backend/profiler.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'answers'
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return {};
});
```

Then I can get the store using StoreManger.lookup(). Ok it's working fine but the question is why ?

PS
I've already tried preloading the model before the store, explicity requiring the model and the store in many place It doesn't looks like a precedence error

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't extend JsonStore, just extend Store. Also, why are you declaring it as a singleton?

Comment: Thanks using Store instead of JsonStore it's working but why ? I've created a Singleton because I tought that I need a single store of this type in my entire application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have many stores which could be made singleton, but it seems that `singleton:true` isn't part of ExtJS best practices.

If we need a "singleton store", which is like 90% of the time, we still make a normal store, but add that store to the stores array in Application.js, so that the instance is created before Application launch. What makes the store a singleton is a `storeId`, by which it is referenced from everywhere. All our singleton stores are defined using a special constructor/callParent construction, because we didn't get reader rootProperty to work otherwise:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Directories',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'DirectoryStore',

    constructor: function() {
        var me = this;
        this.callParent([{
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                headers:{'Accept':'application/json'},
                noCache: true,
                pageParam: false,
                startParam: false,
                limitParam: false,
                extraParams: {
                    q: 'directory'
                },
                url: '../api/AddressBook',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        }]);
    }   
});
```

The special constructor/callParent part makes the difference here. We don't exactly know WHY it works, but it works - we copied that approach from Sencha Architect-generated code. If we now need that store's content anywhere, we do as follows:

```
xtype:'combo',
name:'Directory',
store:'DirectoryStore' // <- reference by storeId!
```

The storeId reference fails if we don't add the store to the stores array in `Application.js`, where we should keep a list of all "singleton" stores:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'MyApp',

    views: [
        /* Allgemein */
        ...
    ],
    controllers: [
        'Configuration',
        ...
    ],
    stores: [
        'Directories',
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've abandoned the idea of having a singleton store it was just an improvements but unnecessary and by subclassing Ext.data.Store instead of Ext.data.JsonStore it's working correctly. I don't know why I can't subclass JsonStore directly but it doesn't metter. Thanks again for your explaination

Comment: Have a look into the `JsonStore.js` code and think about what is happening and when.